# Saving users current location as geopoint using parse.com in javaScript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, geopoints

Hi there I am new to javaScript. What I would like to do is get the users location and save it as a geoPoint to my parse.com database. I have searched their docs and worked out the basics of how to do it but need a little help. I am getting the geoPoint by performing the following:

```
var point = new Parse.GeoPoint.current;
```

and trying to save it by performing:

```
testObject.set("geoPoint", point);
```

In my geoPoint column on parse.com it gets saved as `{"_rejected":false,"_rejectedCallbacks":[],"_resolved":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[]}`

I'm assuming this is because the location is attempting to be saved before the location has actually been found.

So my question is how do I wait until the location is found before sending it to parse?

In the parse docs they say to use `Parse.GeoPoint.current(options)`

but I'm not too sure how to go about this options part. I'm really hoping someone can give me some sample code on how to use `options.success`

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Parse.GeoPoint.current(options) Creates a GeoPoint with the
>   user's current location, if available. Calls options.success with a
>   new GeoPoint instance or calls options.error. Parameters: {Object}
>   options An object with success and error callbacks.
>   - https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.GeoPoint.html

Bascially, you can do:

```
Parse.GeoPoint.current({
    success: function (point) {
        //use current location
        console.log(point);
    }
});
```